# How to close bootstrap angular modal after redirect?

Tags: angular, bootstrap-modal, angular-bootstrap, bootstrap5-modal

I am trying to close a boostrap modal after i navigate to a page. However when i navigate to the page the modal stays open. I tried to use the close method from the activeModal class but still stays open. This is my code:

```
  viewNewLocationPage(): void {
    this.router.navigate(['/locations/new']);
    this.activeModal.close();
  }
```

Comment: Please create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) 
showing the problem.
You could use 
[stackblitz](https://www.stackblitz.com) to make one.

Comment: close the model before redirecting

Answer (score 1):

Close the modal before you navigate? Navigation happens instantly, so code afterwards doesn't execute. Or subscribe to navigate event and close it on event.

```js
  viewNewLocationPage(): void {
    this.activeModal.close();
    this.router.navigate(['/locations/new']); 
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try do like this:

```
this.router.navigate(['/locations/new']).then(() => this.activeModal.close());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the button to a link tag in the html.

eg.

`<a [routerLink]="['/home']" class="btn btn-outline-dark" (click)="d('Save click')">Payment</a>`

Thia will redirect and close the modal.